# Row-wise dot product between matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, inner-products, computational-mathematics

Consider two matrices $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ with rows $a_i\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and $b_i\in\mathbb{R}^m$ respectively. I would like to compute the dot product of each row and *store them in a vector*
$$
c =  \begin{pmatrix} a_1^\top b_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n^\top b_n \end{pmatrix}
$$

Does this operation have a name?

Comment: Is this not just the same thing as computing the trace of the matrix multiplication of $A B^{T}$ i.e $\gamma = \text{Tr }(A B^{T})$?

Comment: @mattos yes it does, but I made a mistake, I meant storing them in a vector, without actually computing the sum of its elements sorry

Comment: If you were to do this in Python, the most obvious way would be 1. First, compute $AB^{T}$ as $x = \text{numpy.matmul}(A, \text{numpy.transpose}(B))$ and then 2. [Retrieve the diagonal elements in the array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html) by computing $c = \text{numpy.diagonal}(x)$. Combined into one step, you have $$c = \text{numpy.diagonal}(\text{numpy.matmul}(A, \text{numpy.transpose}(B)))$$

Comment: @Physics_Student To shorten mattos' one-step code somewhat, we could write

`c = numpy.diag(A@B.T)`

Where `A` and `B` are numpy arrays. We could also use

`c = numpy.sum(A*B, axis = 1)`.

Comment: Just so you know, @BenGrossmann's answer that sums the elementwise product $A$*$B$ along the rows is a much better choice than computing the matrix product of $A$ and the transpose of $B$ as I suggested originally, especially for large arrays.

Comment: In terms of speed, I've found: ````Python
np.einsum("ij,ij->i", A, B)
```` to be the best solution in python. It does exactly what was mentioned in the comments but even faster. I'm still struggling to find a good mathematical notation for this though. Any ideas?

Comment: Implementation questions are not really appropriate on Math SE.  We can address your mathematical question, but implementation is up to you (maybe ask on SO?).